# Create a proxy to simulate a windows or web service with feature auto-responder

Tags: c#, .net

The customer provide me a web API service (ex: `http://webservice:1234`). My website point to web API service directly to get data, ... However, for a purpose of testing, I want to build a proxy (web or windows service) and my website will point to this proxy indirectly. The proxy allow to create many conditions, if request match any condition, the proxy will handle web request itself, ex: return a sample web response. Otherwise, the proxy will point to web API service to get data and return data to my website (indirect).

Please give me any available source code or tool or help me to do this. Thanks.

Comment: would you consider using node.js to do this ? This is really easy to do in node.js with the `http-proxy` module. An other option is to use fiddler, this is really easy to set up with an auto-responder ( trivial  even)

Comment: Is this proxy just for testing? Will it exists in the production environment or will just "die" in the development computers? Will suffice a simple .NET project that you run when testing?

Comment: Side note: "Please give me any available source code or tool or help me to do this" is explicit off-topic on SO. You may want to reword your question to be on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little broad as it stands, but this is the gist.

I would probably just make a web application project. You could use OWIN to run it as a command line if need be, but then you can let ASP handle request parsing and all that. You could also use an HTTPListener, but I don't really see the value in one of those these days.

Once you've got that set up, your ASP project can contain either an [HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx), or just by writing middleware on OWIN. In your function, whichever you choose, you'll want to read the request, elect *how* you want to respond (synthetically or by forwarding it onto the API), then do that. If you want to respond locally, that's easy enough. Just do whatever you'd normally do. Otherwise, you can send an `HttpWebRequest` off to your actual desired API, then return the value.

This is the cleanest and easiest, but you should be aware that some issues exist with this approach. For instance, SSL doesn't work well through it. In order to gain all the functionality of a real proxy, you'll want to set up a TCP Socket that listens, manually parses, and responds as necessary. The decision between these approaches is mostly dependent on how much control you need, versus how little work you want to do.

Long story short, the idea of a proxy is, obviously, to accept a request and forward it accordingly. So you can use whatever framework to do that you choose.

You could also just try and use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for this. I recognize the desire and benefits to write your own, proprietary version that's a little more custom, but Fiddler is certainly easier if it does everything you need it to. I've never actually used the features, but I know it has some features that will let you automatically intercept and respond to requests. [FiddlerCore](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore) would also work (the documentation for it is easily accessible through that link), I've actually been using that a lot the last couple days, albeit in a bit different of a situation. Realistically, it'd probably be better than the sockets or HTTP Listener approach. But it all depends on what you want to accomplish. From the sound of what you're saying, the Fiddler application is going to be your best bet. Then you don't even have to write anything, which can be a good thing. The only real issue with either of these last two is that you'd have to worry about licensing if you were going to publish this as production. "Worrying about" might yield no legitimate concern, but you'd have to at least put thought into it. But if it's staying for testing, that should be fine.